# How can i use OntriggerEnter2D on unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

I'm making a Unity game, in which I'm trying to catch the ball while rolling across a hole.I want to get the ball's speed to judge wheather it will be caught.I attached following code to my hole.But it doesn't work and said that there are no rigidbody2d in my hole.It's wired that other.gameObject is the ball, but other.gameObject.GetComponent().velocity belongs to the hole.How can i fix it?
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class ballcatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trigger stay");
        Vector2 Velocity = other.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity;
        Debug.Log(Velocity.magnitude);
        if (Velocity.magnitude < 0.5)
        {
            Debug.Log(Velocity.magnitude);
            Debug.Log("catch the ball");
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use OnTriggerEnter2D,or OnTriggerEnter, bug doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a `Rigidbody2D` to your hole GameObject? `Collider2D` won't work without one. If you don't want the hole to be affected by physics, set the body type to [kinematic](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyType2D.Kinematic.html). Also, check if you've set the hole's collider to be a trigger, otherwise the `OnTrigger` functions won't be called.

Also, `OnTriggerStay` will be called every (fixed) frame the colliders are interacting, while `OnTriggerEnter` will only be called once when the colliders start interacting. So, `OnTriggerEnter` would be the preferred function for your use case.

Please let me know if this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is solved. I found that the movement script i used in my ball doesn't actually change its speed, just transform its position. So the judgment of the Velocity.magnitude usually fails.